# Django - queryset values return the same model multiple time for each category of a same model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm returning a json object from my views to my client side.

Thus, in order to keep the code as simple as possible, here is what I do:

```
 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        inspirations = Inspiration.objects.active_translations(get_language()).filter(publish=True)
        inspirationsFilter = inspirations.values('translations__title', 
            'translations__slug', 'categories__translations__name', 'main_image__file')

        data = JsonResponse(list(inspirationsFilter), safe=False)
        return HttpResponse(data, status=200, content_type='application/json')
```

But the problem I'm facing here, is this one, from a print with only categories and titles:

```
[('First Inspiration!', 'category1'), ('Hey max how are you', 'category2'), ('A third inspiration', 'category1'), ('A third inspiration', 'category2')]
```

As you can see, "A third inspiration" has 2 categories associated, thus it returns the item for each category.

What I would like to have is something similar to:

```
...('A third inspiration', ['category1', 'category2'])]
```

categories is a ManyToMany model field created by me, translations is a ManyToMany from django-parler.

Thus, do you know of a solution to "concat" it? Or do I have to do it manually?
I've tried values_list but the return is the same.

Edit: until the call to .values, the models query are unique.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing duplicate rows due to the (implicit) join to the translations table.

[This is actually noted in Parler's readme](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler#special-notes) -- so try adding `.distinct('id')`.

Comment: Ok, indeed I've only on "third inspirations". But it only contains "category2" when I want to have all the categories linked to it.